# Deleting multiple values from the list

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have defined one list as

```
List<List<int>> thirdLevelIntersection = new List<List<int>>();
```

I wrote the code as

```
for(int i = 0; i < 57; i++)
{
    if(my condition)
        thirdLevelIntersection[i] = null;
    else
    {
       //some logic
    }    
}
```

so i get the list for 0 to 56 values and some arbitrary values are null like  thirdlevelIntersection[1],thirdlevelIntersection[10],thirdlevelIntersection[21],thirdlevelIntersection[21],thirdlevelIntersection[14],thirdlevelIntersection[15],thirdlevelIntersection[51](total 7).

Now i want to remove this values from the list.

And have a list from thirdlevelIntersection[0] thirdlevelIntersection[49].

What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're creating `thirdLevelIntersection` from a `sourceCollection` of some type you can use Linq.

```
List<List<int>> thirdLevelIntersection = 
    (from item in sourceCollection
     where !(my condition)
     select item)
    .ToList();
```

Or if you're building up the list over multiple statements you can do it as you are creating it:

```
thirdLevelIntersection.AddRange(
    from item in sourceCollection
    where !(my condition)
    select item);
```

This eliminates the necessity to remove items from a list once they've been added.

Comment: It works..but it is too tough for a fresher like me..to understand linq..can u tel proper source..from where..i can have an idea of linq..nd thanks for the answer

Comment: @user2213564 Best place to learn Linq is [here](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b).

Answer (score 3):

Once you are done with your loop, try

```
thirdLevelIntersection.RemoveAll(list => list == null);
```

Comment: You're welcome. But technically, this isn't Linq. RemoveAll is an instance method of List<T>, whereas Linq (-to-objects) is implemented as extension methods on IEnumerable<T>.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this while you're iterating over the list by calling `RemoveAt()` and then decrementing `i` (so the next value is considered).

```
List<List<int>> thirdLevelIntersection = new List<List<int>>();

for(int i=0;i<57;i++)
{
    if (my condition)
    {
        thirdLevelIntersection.RemoveAt(i--);
        continue;
    }
    else
    {
        //some logic
    }
}
```